# Retrosynthesis of (2E)-1-(2,4-dimethylphenyl)-3-(thiophen-2-yl)prop-2-en-1-one

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, carbonyl-compounds, organosulfur-compounds, retrosynthesis

I am struggling to find a way to disconnect this molecule and I am unsure of the order:

[image: (2E)-1-(2,4-dimethylphenyl)-3-(thiophen-2-yl)prop-2-en-1-one]

First, I was thinking of disconnecting the C=C of the α,β-unsaturated carbonyl. Then for the thiophene group disconnecting the formyl substituent, then disconnecting the thiophene either side of the sulfur atom to give a 1,4-diketone.

Then for the benzene substituent: disconnecting the carbonyl first (via Friedel–Crafts acylation), as the methyl groups will be *ortho*/*para*-directing.

Would this be the correct order?

Comment: Synthesis of compound **T11** in https://doi.org/10.1002/ardp.201100005 should be a good hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several approaches to this molecule, but I think the key disconnection is the *E*-double bond. This looks like it can be formed by a [Horner-Emmons-Wadsworth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%E2%80%93Wadsworth%E2%80%93Emmons_reaction) reaction between the widely commercially thiophene-2-carboxaldehyde and a ketophosphonate derived from 2,4-dimethylacetophenone. HEW reactions give predominantly *E*-alkenes which is the reason for the choice.

The ketophosphonate can be prepared in good yield from the commercially available 2,4-dimethylbenzoyl chloride by reaction with diethyl phosphonoacetic acid/MgCl2/Et3N, method described [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00397910008087362?journalCode=lsyc20).

It is possible to prepare both starting materials, but it is an important principle of synthetic chemistry that your time as a researcher is more valuable than the cost of advanced materials. If a starting material is available, buy it.